# How to use babel-loader in gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

I can't seem to find how to include `babel-loader` in my gatsby project. I need to use the `transform-imports` plugin from `babel` to simplify importing in development mode while not sacrificing size in production build.

In my other projects I do the following:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: [
                    [
                        "env",
                        {
                            targets: {
                                browsers: [">1%", "last 4 versions", "Firefox ESR", "not ie < 9"]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "stage-0",
                    "react"
                ],
                plugins: [
                    "lodash",
                    [
                        "transform-imports",
                        {
                            "redux-form": {
                                transform: "redux-form/es/${member}",
                                preventFullImport: true
                            }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add plugin and config to .babelrc file:

```
{
 "presets" : [...],
 "plugins" : [..., ["transform-imports", { "redux-form" : { ... } } ] ]
}
```

Comment: You probably meant .babelrc